# What is the Equivalent of Single Pipe Symbol in MySQL on AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**Sample SQL Command in MySQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE COLUMN_X = 'X' | SELECT COLUMN_Y CASE // single pipe symbol
WHEN A - B = 0 THEN 'A' 
WHEN B - C = 0 THEN 'B' 
ELSE 'Z' END FROM TABLE_A;
```

**What function or symbol should I use on Redshift in place of the single pipe symbol?** If there isn't any function or symbol equivalent, how should I construct the to-be SQL command?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE COLUMN_X = 'X' ?? SELECT COLUMN_Y CASE
WHEN A - B = 0 THEN 'A' 
WHEN B - C = 0 THEN 'B' 
ELSE 'Z' END FROM TABLE_A;
```

Additional Info

- The single pipe symbol represents bitwise OR in MySQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql

Comment: What is the actual logic of the first query?

Comment: Is `|` being used an `OR`?

Comment: Based on the documentation I found, it represents bitwise OR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql

Comment: `bit_or` should work : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BIT_OR.html